# "commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules"

Tags: gitlab, git-commit

Since this morning I have a problem for committing my work :

I tried several commands to clean up my local repo but I still have the same problem, I have searched well in other topics where the problems encountered were similar to mine but the solutions differ without me being able to adapt anything ...

I await your answers

[image]

PS : Sorry for my lack of courtesy but obviously Stack Overflow does not want me to greet you ...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! No worries on the courtesy- it may feel weird but this is really not supposed to be a discussion board - it’s meant to be an archive of clean questions and answers which are useful to others. “Thanks” etc just get in the way of future users’ understanding. It’s not my policy and took a while for me to get used to too but you’ll get the hang of it. Probably best if you remove the “I await” and “PS” lines. Promise we won’t be offended :)

Comment: For your question, it would be really helpful if you included what you have tried rather than just saying that you’ve tried lots of things that didn’t work. That way we don’t have to go through them all too. Check out the guide to [ask]. Good luck!

Comment: Add what you tried to the question, not comments please.

Comment: I had tried :
git add *
git commit -m "message"
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -fxd
git commit -a -m "message"

But nothing working

Comment: Can you edit your question with this information? And make sure it’s formatted as a [code block](/help/formatting). Generally, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: My edit is disable ...

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not clear what you want to achieve exactly but to add the open change for committing just use

```
git add conFusion
```

Then you can commit again.

```
git commit -m "your description"
```

And finally push with

```
git push origin master
```

wheras `origin master` never seems to be required in your situation, so just `git push` will likely be enough.
I'm not sure why `git commit -a` didn't work, but the reason might be that the message with the parameter `-m` was missing.

Here you can find documentation about

- [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)
- [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)
- [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Comment: Thank you, my problem was solved with your instructions !